# Operator hats with simpler-wick package

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am using the `simpler-wick` package for Wick contractions. A simple contraction could be written as:

```latex
\wick{\c A \c B}
```

This works fine, but I would like to have operator hats on the operators I am contracting. So, I would like to do the following:

```latex
\wick{\c \hat{A} \c \hat{B}}
```

This fails to compile - I don't get an error/warning, but the compiler just runs forever. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The package proposes a lame syntax: I'd prefer something like `\c{A}` and, when indices are needed, `\c[1]{A}`. With such syntax, one would not be misled and would naturally type `\c{\hat{A}}`. Alas, this is not how the package does.

Comment: @marmot The level index. `;-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does compile if you use the appropriate syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\begin{document}
$\wick{\c A \c B}$ $\wick{\c {\hat{A}} \c {\hat{B}}}$
$\wick[offset=1.2em,sep=0.4em]{\c {\widehat{A}} \c {\widehat{B}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The last example shows a possible way to lift the bar.

Comment: Thanks so much!